# Find sensitive data/way tool

Tags: password

For an IT challenge, I've been asked to find all sensitive data (bookmarks, browsing history, pictures, videos, logs,passwords, ... ) on a protected Windows host machine.

So far, I've been able to access this machines files by booting with Ubuntu from an USB stick. However, the machine has lots of data, organized in an unfriendly way and randomly searching is pretty fruitless.

Any recommended tools to be able to efficiently find data in such a setup?

Comment: time is not strictly limited but going through files and file names might not be a good idea. For example, how would I find browser history? in what type of file or name is that stored? Perhaps there is a program that can do this for me, and that is what the question is about.

Comment: I see, will remove the comment.